# How to pass output of grep to sed?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a command like this :

```
cat error | grep -o [0-9]
```

which is printing only numbers like `2`,`30` and so on. Now I wish to pass *this* number to `sed`.

Something like :

```
cat error | grep -o [0-9] | sed -n '$OutPutFromGrep,$OutPutFromGrepp'
```

Is it possible to do so?

I'm new to shell scripting. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not try it out? Note that $ variables in single quotes are not expanded. If you want that, put them in double quotes instead.

Comment: I tried this `echo cat error | grep -o [0-9] | sed -n "$1,$1"` which results in error : `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'`

Comment: Regarding `cat error | grep -o [0-9]`: [Don't Grep the Cat](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/12/13/dont-grep-the-cat/).

Comment: You have a problem with your `sed` command, which we don't see. `$1` is a shell parameter. What's its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the intention is to print the lines that `grep` returns, generating a `sed` script might be the way to go:

```
grep -E -o '[0-9]+' error | sed 's/$/p/' | sed -f - error
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), particularly the `-I` option:

```
themel@eristoteles:~$ xargs -I FOO echo once FOO, twice FOO
hi
once hi, twice hi
there
once there, twice there
```

Your example:

```
themel@eristoteles:~$ cat error
error in line 123
error in line 234
errors in line 345 and 346
themel@eristoteles:~$ grep -o '[0-9]*' < error | xargs -I OutPutFromGrep echo sed -n 'OutPutFromGrep,OutPutFromGrepp'
sed -n 123,123p
sed -n 234,234p
sed -n 345,345p
sed -n 346,346p
```

For real-world use, you'll probably want to pass `sed` an input file and remove the `echo`.

(Fixed your [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), by the way. )

Comment: +1 Nice. `cat error | grep -o [0-9]+` After this I have the *data*, now how I can pass it to `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass output from grep to sed.

Please note that in order to match whole numbers you need to use [0-9]* not only [0-9] which would match only a single digit.

Also note you should use double quotes to get variables expanded(in the sed argument) and it seems you have a typo in the second variable name.

Hope this helps.